# Can you tell me a better approach in designing a table for banned users than this?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am designing a web application and I need to give the administrators and moderators the right to allow and deny other users access to the application. I am thinking of having a table with the following columns:

1. OperationType (Ban / Access regained).
2. BannedUser
3. User (admin/mod that gave access or banned another user)
4. EventDate
5. Reason (optional)

I can just have a table, storing all banned users, but I want to keep track of what is actually happening in the app and make sure that the administrators and moderators are not misbehaving as well.

So, If my table doesn't include an OperationType column, a list of all the banned users could be retrieved as simple as writing the following query:

```
select BannedUser from UserBan;
```

But if I leave the table with an OperationType column, as shown above, my simple select query could become something like this:

```
select o3.BannedUser
from 
(
select o1.BannedUser, max(o1.EventDate) EventDate
from UserBan o1
group by o1.BannedUser
) o2, UserBan o3 
where o3.EventDate = o2.EventDate and
o3.BannedUser = o2.BannedUser and
o3.OperationType = 1
```

Assume that OperationType = 1 is ban.

So, can someone give me a better solution for my case? :)

Comment: How does a banned user regain access? Is it based on elapsed time?

Comment: Nope, the idea was that an admin/moderator is the one who bans or revokes the ban.

Comment: Don't think you need OperationType. If they exist in the table they are banned, if not they are not.